# ADB over network, no option to enable in device

Tags: android, networking, adb

I'm looking for the most efficient way to load an apk onto 30 tablets at the same time (or swiftly one after another) using a script to send commands. Effectively I'd like to plug in all my tablets to the network, run over to my computer, and run a script that will iterate through all recognized IP addresses and push the apk to them. **I want to completely eliminate the need to connect any tablet to USB.** This is the most important part.

My understanding is that this is possible, but I've run into an issue that I can't seem to find an answer for.

The option to enable "adb over network/wifi" is not available in my devices. They are all on Android version 4.4.2. I can't seem to find any notes about this functionality being added into later versions. Is this the case?